# I would like to know how to get a pyomo.core.base.set.SetProduct_OrderedSet domain values?

Tags: python, pyomo

[image: This is a variable from an instance in a abstract model python. I would like to store in a list [REGION, TECHNOLOGY, YEAR] but I haven't found a method to get it. I've created a list for each of the variables manually, but it takes a lots of lines code. REGION, TECHNOLOGY and YEAR are sets of my problem.]

**This is how it is defined the variable in the problem:**

`model.v_AccumulatedNewCapacity =  Var(model.REGION, model.TECHNOLOGY, model.YEAR,domain = NonNegativeReals)`

**This will print all variables in the model without head column names:**

```
for v in instance.component_objects(Var, active=True):
print("Variable",v)  
for index in v:
    print ("   ",index, value(v[index]))
```

**I want to get that to add it to the information of the output of each variable**

| REGION | TECHNOLOGY | YEAR | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VC | PWR | 2019 | 2023 |

Answer (score 1):

The domain in your screen shot is the cross product of your `REGION`, `TECHNOLOGY`, and `YEAR` indexing sets. You should see the full list of set members in the "Members" column when you call `pprint` on that indexing set.

If you're asking how to get a list of that cross product to do something else with it there are a couple different options:

```
# Manually take the cross product
list(model.REGION*model.TECHNOLOGY*model.YEAR)

# Grab the indices from the Var object
list(model.v_AccumulatedNewCapacity.index_set())
```

Comment: I get `[('VC', 'PWR', 2019)]` and I was expecting a list  with `[REGION, TECHNOLOGY, YEAR]`. Those are going to be the head columns for the output. I want in the output file head columns like the following ones:
| REGION| TECHNOLOGY| YEAR    | VALUE|
|:--------|:---------|:------|:-----------------------:|
| VC| PWR   | 2019  | 23 |